# Retrieve process path from pid in kernel extension OSX

Tags: macos, kernel-extension

I am making a kernel extension for osx 10.11.x (El Capitan). Currently, I have got pid from *proc_selfpid()*

Then, I get process name from function *proc_procname()* 
Now, I need to get the path of process from pid but I cannot find any api in kernel space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve path of process from OSX 10.10/10.11 kernel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739742/retrieve-path-of-process-from-osx-10-10-10-11-kernel)